# Is there a reverse proxy for Solace Message Router?

Tags: solace

IBM has MQIPT (IBM MQ Internet Pass-Thru) that acts as MQ forwarder/reverse proxy to implement messaging solutions between remote sites across the internet.  Is there such an equivalence for Solace?

Answer (score 0):

Solace has all kinds of fancy advanced features for load balancing and hybrid/multi-site deployments like bridges and dynamic message routing, but I don't really know those, and where's the fun in having everything ready-made and pre-solved for you anyway? :-)

So here I am going to assume you want to roll your own solution and use an actual reverse proxy:

You can switch to HTTP-based protocols, and just use any regular HTTP reverse proxy. Solace message brokers have a REST message interface, or if your application already uses the Solace API for messaging (or needs its advanced features), you can switch over to HTTP streaming or WebSockets as a transport by modifying the scheme portion of the broker URL in your application configuration. (http:// or ws:// instead of tcp://) This will only allow you to balance sessions, not individual messages within a single elephant flow.

Comment: Thanks, Szocske.  I am looking more for "hiding" Solace from the external clients (either using JMS or Solace JCSMP, for e.g.) so that the clients are not directly connected to Solace.  This is what MQIPT is doing. I think I can use Layer 4 reverse proxy for this, such as HAProxy or NGINX.